# Does the Toomey-Manchin proposal include a federal gun registry?

Tags: united-states, guns

While researching the gun control debate in the US, this caught my eye:

> Mr Biden also accused the nation's top gun rights lobbying group, the National Rifle Association (NRA), of spreading disinformation, and promised expanded background checks would not lead to a national gun registry.
>
> <sub>Source: [US Senate opens first gun control debate in years](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-us-canada-22111383) - BBC</sub>

Does the Toomey-Manchin background check proposal include a federal gun registry or not? And if not, does it include provisions that may lead to a federal gun registry in the near future?

Answer (score 1):

It does not. All gun purchase records on kept a) on paper b) not digitized and c) only stored at the location of purchase. This is actually part of the current laws and the proposals do nothing to change that.

NPR did an overview of the process today: http://www.npr.org/2013/04/11/176954637/gun-registration-paper-trail-is-long-and-convoluted

Comment: I can't find a citation for it right now but I think I also read that there are maximum limits on how long the detail paperwork can be kept, i.e. it must be destroyed within a certain amount of time after the sale.

Comment: That is the current process.  The proproal includes sending the specifics of the weapons being purchased with the back ground checks, and would be collected for use by the government in analysis.  But as we learned with the baseball steriods, statistic collection means that eventually the details get used not just the statistics.

Comment: Is there any proof that there are no records of background checks saved/cached somewhere in a database? Just because a proposal doesn't explicitly authorizes such a registry, without explicit language prohibiting such data collection the registry DB is likely to be created in the future, even if not for ostensible "registry" purposes.

Comment: My answer pertains to the purchase records--the ones stored by the seller. I don't know the status or process of background check records or the specifics of how that works.

Comment: (or for that matter, if background checks are even 'records' of any sort that are kept...that's likely another good question!)

Comment: This article mentions that the propose bill explicitly forbids the creation of a central registry: http://www.csmonitor.com/USA/DC-Decoder/2013/0411/Gun-background-checks-How-would-Senate-proposal-work-exactly-video/(page)/2 but I'm still not sure if a background check, itself, actually produces a record of any sorts anywhere. It seems like it would have to--but perhaps that's recorded with the gun sale paperwork.

Comment: Ah yes, it looks like the background check is part of the paperwork the seller keeps: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Form_4473 So that leaves the question: is there any other record of the background check stored anywhere?